# Подчёркивание нижней границы в EditText

Tags: android, android-studio, android-edittext

Есть форма заполнения логина и пароля. Цвет фона EditText совпадает с цветом фона background. Нужно подчеркнуть нижнюю границу EditText.
Вот код EditText:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
    android:background="#8bcdc5"
    android:hint="Логин"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textColorHint="#025962" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:background="#8bcdc5"
    android:hint="Пароль"
    android:textColorHint="#025962"
    android:padding="10dp" />
```

[image: Как сейчас]

[image: Как нужно]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В EditText подчёркивание задано по умолчанию. В данном случае, чтобы подчёркивание появилось, нужно просто убрать определитель цвета фона (android:background="#8bcdc5")

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать это программно. Установить белый цвет, например:

```
editText
    .getBackground()
    .setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.white), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
```

Удалить цвет:

```
editText.getBackground().clearColorFilter();
```

Comment: Можете, пожалуйста, пояснить. Куда конкретно нужно прописать ваши строчки кода?

Comment: EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText); editText.getBackground().setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.white), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN); Добавить в метод onCreate вашей активити.